# Phalcon + PHPUnit + DI: Too many db connections

Tags: mysql, phpunit, phalcon

I'm using PHPUnit with Phalcon.  In my UnitTestCase (base test class), I've set up the connection thus:

```
protected function setUp(\Phalcon\DiInterface $di = null, \Phalcon\Config $config = null)
{
    $dbparams = ...

    if (is_null($di)) {
        $di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
    }

    $di->setShared('db', function() use ($dbconfig) {
        return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($dbparams);
    });

    \Phalcon\DI:setDefault($di);

    parent::setUp($di, $this->_config);

    $this->_loaded = true;
}
```

I'm running into a problem, where, after a number of suites are run, I'm starting to get the following error (on every one of the test cases after a certain point):

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So you just keep adding new connections with each test case. Since PHPUnit runs a single PHP process, none of the database connections are garbage-collected. The PHP process just keeps accumulating open connections until you exceed the database instance's `max_connections` value.

You can probably observe the number of connections growing if you open a session to MySQL and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` from time to time.

You need to disconnect from the database in your PHPUnit `tearDown()` method.